# How to find Average from mysql table in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to calculate average for r1-r25 columns in ratings table.There will be null values in the columns represented by value 99.How to find the average for 25 columns in efficient manner?
The sample code I used for a single column is as follows,

Sample PHP code

```
$s=0;
$n=0; 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratings");  

while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($res)){    
    $rat=$arr['r1'];
    if($rat != 99)
    {
        $s=$rat+$s;
        $n=$n+1;
        $avg=$s/$n; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: Why not exclude the `99`s in your SQL?

Comment: It there is time in your project to normalise your database, now might be a good time. This seems awfully messy to me. And "99" for NULL values is bad.

Comment: but i need to do lot of calculations based on the 25 calculated averages.If I normalize the table means it will be more complex to calculate.

Comment: I'll change the 99 Values as NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE `r1` NOT IN ( 99 )");
```

Now you don't need `if` check in your while loop.

Comment: but i need to find the average separately for 25 columns can you help by giving some more hints?

Comment: Try a PHP loop to get all the sums separately. For example
`<?php for($r=1; $r<=25; $r++) { } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the database for this work:

```
SELECT AVG(case when r1 <> 99 then r1 end) as r1_avg,
       AVG(case when r2 <> 99 then r2 end) as r2_avg,
       . . .
       AVG(case when r25 <> 99 then r25 end) as r25_avg     
FROM ratings;
```

This will be faster because you don't have to bring all the data over to the application for sequential processing.

It does require more typing (or use a spreadsheet to generate the code).  This is because you are storing data in columns, when the data should really be in separate rows -- one row per whatever and the rating (and perhaps a rating number).  With that data structure, the query would be both shorter and better performing.

Also, SQL has a great mechanism for storing `NULL` values, and you should use it.  It is called `NULL`, not "99".

Comment: But I need to give some constraints too.If there is no column after r4 means,it should calculate the mean values for r1,r2,r3,r4 columns in 4 variables only.can you elaborate?

Comment: yeah...will try the NULL values too !